# How to preserve order of content in Kotlin collection

Tags: kotlin

How to preserve the order in which content is added to collections in Kotlin?

In python there is
`collections.OrderedDict()`

Comment: [`LinkedHashMap`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-linked-hash-map/) sounds like what you are looking for - _"The insertion order is preserved by maintaining a doubly-linked list of all of its entries."_

Comment: What collection? There are some collections that preserve the order by default other don't `List` should preserve it.  Also, do you want to sort it maybe?

Comment: Also, the MutableMap that is returned by `mutableMapOf` is documented to preserve insertion order, because it's actually using LinkedHashMap under the hood. It theoretically could be changed to return some other implementation of the interface, but they will not change it to something that doesn't preserve order, since the guarantee was made in the documentation.